# updating Widget using BroadcastReceiver in Main Activity

Tags: android, android-widget, broadcastreceiver

I am developing a android widget which consist of a clock. Till now i am able to successfully set the clock to present time but can't update it. I am using `Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK` broadcast receiver. 
I am registering the Broadcast Receiver in `onEnable()` and deleting on `onDeleted()`. The Receiver is registering and unregistering correctly but the problem arises when i update the `views`. Here is the code that i am using

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(final Context context) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Entering onstart");
    _broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
            System.out.println("Registering BroadCast");
            if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0) {

                System.out.println(_sdfWatchTime.format(new Date()));
                //class to get drawable images that will be used to denote hours and minutes
                GetDrawableResources getDrawableResources = new GetDrawableResources();
                int time[] = new int[new GetTime().getTime(context
                        .getApplicationContext()).length];
                //class to get each digit of time seperatly eg 10:10, separating 1 0 1 0 working correctly
                time = new GetTime().getTime(context
                        .getApplicationContext());

                //changing views
                for (int i = 0; i < awID.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("awID for " + awID[i]);
                    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(
                            context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                            R.layout.activity_main);

                    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.ivHour0,
                            getDrawableResources.setTimeDrawable(time[0]));
                    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.ivHour1,
                            getDrawableResources.setTimeDrawable(time[1]));
                    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.ivMinute0,
                            getDrawableResources.setTimeDrawable(time[2]));
                    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.ivMinute1,
                            getDrawableResources.setTimeDrawable(time[3]));
                    //problem is pointing to line below
                    awm.updateAppWidget(awID[i], views);

                }

            }
        }
    };
    context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(_broadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
    super.onEnabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length; // more than 1 same widget added
    awID = new int[N];
    awID = appWidgetIds;
    awm = appWidgetManager;

    for (int t : awID) {
        System.out.println("awID onUpdate" + t);
    }

}
```

error that i am getting

```
    06-28 11:27:00.078: E/AndroidRuntime(453): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 11:27:00.078: E/AndroidRuntime(453): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x40000004 (has extras) } in com.itcse.weather.MainActivity$1@40520228
06-28 11:27:00.078: E/AndroidRuntime(453):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:722)
06-28 11:27:00.078: E/AndroidRuntime(453):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-28 11:27:00.078: E/AndroidRuntime(453):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-28 11:27:00.078: E/AndroidRuntime(453):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-28 11:27:00.078: E/AndroidRuntime(453):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-28 11:27:00.078: E/AndroidRuntime(453):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 11:27:00.078: E/AndroidRuntime(453):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-28 11:27:00.078: E/AndroidRuntime(453):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-28 11:27:00.078: E/AndroidRuntime(453):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-28 11:27:00.078: E/AndroidRuntime(453):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 11:27:00.078: E/AndroidRuntime(453): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 11:27:00.078: E/AndroidRuntime(453):  at com.itcse.weather.MainActivity$1.onReceive(MainActivity.java:57)
06-28 11:27:00.078: E/AndroidRuntime(453):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
06-28 11:27:00.078: E/AndroidRuntime(453):  ... 9 more
```

**Update**
The null error is removed and the code is running successfully but views are not updated.

Answer (score 1):

You got a NullPointerException in your MainActivity line 57:

```
com.itcse.weather.MainActivity$1.onReceive(MainActivity.java:57)
```

You should put a break point there and see what is null.

If you can't get your debugger to stop there (sometimes happens in Receivers), put Debug.waitForDebugger(); before your break point.

Comment: Alright I finally removed the error, turns out that `awm` was null even though i initialized it in `onUpdate`. Anyhow, Now i am not getting any errors but the `ImageViews` are also not updated either, they are same as before.

Comment: Did you remove awm.updateAppWidget(awID[i], views); completely, or just added a null check on aws?